# Convert TeX to XDoc

Tags: conversion, xml

I am rather new in this forum, so that I hope you will be patient in case of naive question.

I would like to know if any of you is aware of ready-made tools to convert a `TeX` document into a [XDoc](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/xdoc/).

So far I have not been able to find anything on the net.

Comment: I am not sure whether these are the same, but did you take a look at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/xdoc?

Comment: @MMA: I think that your post is not related to my question; only matter of homonymy.

Comment: @fpe I also had some doubt, but I could not decide since I was not familiar with either of these. Sorry it did not work out.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there are no tool or tools to do that.

- One point is that your linked XDOC is outdated, as you can read on the linked web site. And there seems not to be new plugin(s) for Maven X to generate XDOC.
- The second point is that the problem seems for me to be very similar to use TeX/LaTeX to create a Word document (file `.docx`.
- As third point you can try to convert a TeX file to HTML or XHTML (XML). An overview for the problematic gives in my opinion question [Leveraging a dynamic preamble to generate multiple output formats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127795/leveraging-a-dynamic-preamble-to-generate-multiple-output-formats)? 
  For more information try to search this side (and the internet) for `tex2html`, `tex2xml` or `pandoc`.